# I wanna create discord bot that reacts gif to all messages with certain word

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need some help with making discord bot. I want that bot to react gif to all messages with certain word like if that message contains word "dog" it reacts to that message with dog gif. I have already setup discord bot in discord developer page now i need help how to get bot working like that.

Comment: Okay, so what happened when you tried to write the code to solve the problem? What happened when you tried reading the documentation on the Discord API? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please read [ask].

Comment: Try to format your question properly as well. It's easier for others to help you if they can actually read your question.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so you probably will want an API to do this and an `on_message` event.

e.g.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    msg.content = msg.content.lower()
    if "dog" in msg.content:
        await ctx.send("link for the dog")
```

You can use this api to get a random link of a dog pic: https://some-random-api.ml/img/dog

And dont use `requests` module, but `aiohttp`.
If you need more help, just ask! This is just an example of how the `on_message` event would look like

Answer (score -1):

You can check message with `on_message` event and use some-random-api to get images.

```
import aiohttp

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "dog" in message.content.lower():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as ses:
            async with ses.get("https://some-random-api.ml/img/dog") as response:
                data = await response.json()
                await ctx.send(data["link"])
```